# nginx server log can not be append

Tags: nginx

nginx(1.12.2) access.log not append, access.log only record one day log, how can I set nginx to slove this problem? thanks

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      # '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '$status $scheme $server_port $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
}
```

Comment: Your post (overly tersely) describes a current state. Please add to your question: *How* is that state a problem, what do you want accomplished? Depending on (e.g. OS) environment, logs may be manipulated "externally".

Comment: It was caused by `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx`